# Compress folder with WinRar and move to another Directory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, winrar

is there anyway to compress a folder to a .rar and move it to another directory? I have tried doing it from a vb.net application and by writing a batch file to do so but im not sure on the contents of the file. Can you help please?

Comment: You should read the documentation for the RAR utility. Does it /have/ to be a .rar file? CSharpZipLib ( http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx ) is free, if a zip archive would do instead.

Comment: It could be any kind any kind of compression just not sure about how to go ahead and do it

Comment: There is example code available to download from the same page I linked to previously.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("""DESTINATION TO WINRAR""", "a -afrar -m5 -ed -pPASSWORDHERE -r -ep1  """ & WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE THE FILE & """ ""DIRECTORY TO BACKUP*""")
```

Comment: Do we include those quotations, just some of them or none of them? Could you please write a better example? Use Variables.
dim WINRARFOLDER as string
dim PASSWORD as string
dim SAVEFILETO as string
etc..